# multiple alert boxes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-plugins

is there any free jQuery plugin that allows me to have

- multiple alerts
- either fading or with ok button
- customize size, color of the alert box
- customize where it is placed on within the browser window

The purpose is to display 'system alerts' for the user. User will log in and during the day he will get alerts boxes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) from jQuery UI or the [overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) from jQuery tools. Not technically plugins, but good for the job (and plenty more besides).

[jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html) is a popular plugin that would probably suit your purpose.

Comment: I am more after something that would display 'system alerts' for the user. The alert box will fade out or have 'ok' button.